# Continue Loop in TextBox to search multiple value from Database, MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've changed the textbox "enter key behavior", so that everytime I hit enter, textbox will go to the next line,

[Project's Form View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDUlU.jpg)

When user Click the Button, subform show result for the first line, but then how to get result in every line user input.

```
Private Sub CountButton_Click()
    Dim SQL As String
    
    SQL = "SELECT database.Tracking, database.Date, DateDiff(""d"",[Date],Date()) As Aeging FROM database;"
                
    Me.Query1_subform.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.Query1_subform.Form.Requery
    
End Sub
```

Do I need to use Loop or VbCrLf or something else to function the textbox

Comment: Seems like table contauns only one row, as without a criteria it fetches all rows. You can get the separated textbox lines by splitting `textbox.Text` on `VbCrLf` (creates an array) and if you search for exact match on characters joining that array on `','` and use that string on an `In` criteria (e.g. `Where Tracking IN ('" & Join(Splitt(textbox.Text, VbCrLf), "','") & "');"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split textbox value to an array and loop array to build comma-separated string or:

```
strIN = Replace(Me.textbox, vbCrLf, "','")
If InStrRev(strIN, "','") > 0 Then strIN = Left(strIN, Len(strIN)-3)
SQL = "SELECT database.Tracking, database.Date, DateDiff('d', [Date], Date()) As Aging " & _ 
"FROM database " & _
"WHERE Tracking IN('" & strIN & "');"
```

Using a textbox relies on users to be consistent with input - not starting input with a CR and no other extraneous characters input accidentally or otherwise.

More reliable alternative is a multi-select listbox of Tracking values. Code loops through selected items and builds comma-separated string.